# Loop single row to get result based on if function

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to do if function for each cell in one row using loop with function. To explain better, here is what I want to do:

```
     A      b       C       D       E
1    al     sl      al      HD      al

2
```

I have the above excel cells in which i want to say in my code in cell `A2`

```
Dim cng As Range
Dim rng As Range

Set rng = Range("A1:E1")

   For Each cng In rng
     If Cells(1, 1) = "al" Then
       Cells(2,1) = 8
        Else
        Cells(2, 1) = 0
        End If
        Next cng
end sub
```

Here I want the code to do the same for `B2`, `C2`, `D2` and `E2` as well.
Thank you very much in advance for your help

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to make the column a variable.
If I got your point you might want to use *Select Case* instead of *If*.

```
Dim cng As Range Dim rng As Range

Set rng = Range("A1:E1")

For Each cng In rng
If Cells(1, rng.Column) = "al"
Then Cells(2,rng.Column) = 8 Else Cells(2, rng.Column) = 0
End If
Next cng
End Sub
```

UPDATE:
Messed up the cng-rng distinction.

```
Sub ert()
Dim cng As Range, rng As Range
Set rng = Range("A1:E1")
For Each cng In rng
    If Cells(1, cng.Column) = "al" Then
        Cells(2, cng.Column) = 8
    Else
        Cells(2, cng.Column) = 0
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: the same issue happened, the result of the first cell comes but not moving to the other cells in the same range. it read only from the first range A1 and stopped while there are other "al" in other cells

Comment: I really appreciate it. you give the exact thing that i want to do. best regards and hope you all the best my friend